# Avoid primary key duplicates in Windows Azure

Tags: sql, azure, unique

In Windows Azure table storage, there is no 'type' that allows an auto incrementing ID. I thought I could use 'IsIdentity' but the checkbox is greyed out (this should give me auto incrementing, right?).

Can anybody advise me on how I can get an auto incrementing field or a workaround please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless, for some reason, you actually need monotonically-increasing numeric keys, then using `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()` is the usual approach. (Because the PartitionKey value on Table Storage is a string, you need to convert it.)

The advantage to this approach is that Table Storage rows are automatically ordered by the PartitionKey (and then by the RowKey), so you'll get the rows back in the order they were inserted, just like an IDENTITY column in SQL Server.

If you want the records returned most-recent-first, then use `(long.MaxValue - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks).ToString()` instead.

Note that the first method will give an 18-digit number for the next 1158 years. If you want to avoid the Y3160 bug, consider padding the value with a leading zero (`DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString("0000000000000000000")`).

The second method will give a 19-digit number for a very long time indeed, way past DateTime.MaxValue, so you're probably OK there.

Also bear in mind that with load-balancing and suchlike, there is a very small possibility that you'll get duplicates if two servers create a record at the exact same time, so you should have retry semantics that increment the key value by one.

Comment: I don't understand the PartitionKey business... Essentially (as I understand it) I use DateTime.Utc.Now.ToString() and store it as a string in my database (as the primary key), right? Thank you for the humorous answer btw!

Comment: `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()` - the Ticks property is the important bit.

Comment: I prefer `(DateTime.MaxValue - DateTime.UtcNow).Ticks.ToString("d19")` for reverse-chronological order. The d19 trick is handy either way. See http://blog.smarx.com/posts/using-numbers-as-keys-in-windows-azure. A little humor there too.

Comment: +1 for the " If you want to avoid the Y3160 bug". It would be a shame if the Eartians in 3160 can't use my app because of this bug.